# Can you send a bash command to the Linux terminal using NASM

Tags: c, linux, assembly, nasm

### Can you send a bash command to the Linux terminal using NASM.

Would like to see if it is possible to do and showing an example of the correct Nasm code used.

Also With or without using the printf Cpp library’s.

And before anyone asks i know it is possible to use BASH its self or Python etc. To do this.

Example commands:

```
ifconfig
groupdel
```

Comment: What's wrong with invoking `system()`?

Comment: How would one use and implement this in NASM? as so far i have just been sticking to the basic system calls etc.

Comment: Use `fork` and `execve` syscalls. Fork to create a new process, execve to load an instance of shell (/bin/sh) with the command as its parameter.

Comment: Yeah that looks correct did not think of that just added eax, 0x02 ; sys_fork and eax, 0x11 ;sys_execve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fork and execve syscalls. First use fork to create a new process. In the new process, use execve to load an instance of shell (/bin/sh) with the arguments `-c` and the command to execute.

And then you'll have your own implementation of C RTL's `system()`.